# Facebook Authenication

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

What would be the best way to integrate facebook authentication with my set of users in ruby on rails. The added thing is I am creating a Android Application that goes with my server. So what is the best way to integrate both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using android app, then in your devise just uncommet the token_authenticable.
For android app you need authentication token. Omniauth and Devise is the best way for facebook authentication.
For facebook authentication, First you have to register your app in facebook and through omniauth you have to access the information for the user like email, name , nickname and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Devise with omniauth would be the best and simplest way to do it.

You should find lots of infos and tutorials on how to do it